# ignore-error on Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, handleerror

I'm trying to handle errors in Common Lisp easily, but I have some problems.

In particular, I have this function.

```
(defun function1 (m)
 (ignore-errors (and (condition-1) (condition-2))
   (format t "Error message")))
```

I just want that if some conditions fail into the

```
(and (condition-1) (condition-2))
```

it's shown the error message, otherwise just

```
T
```

How can I do?
There is a better way to handle this type of errors? I looking for something very simple.

Someone can do an example showing how to use ignore-error?

Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean that `CONDITION-1` and `CONDITION-2` are forms that may signal an error condition, or are they just forms that return a boolean?

Comment: @jkiiski both. condition-1 could be - a call to a function that should return a boolean, or an error - or simply a boolean expression.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I'm trying man, I'm a newbie on Common Lisp, I just want to show a message if some of the code above signal an error, or return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HANDLER-CASE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_hand_1.htm#handler-case)

```
CL-USER 101 > (handler-case (and (evenp 2)
                                 (oddp 1))
               (error (c)
                 (princ c)
                 (values)))
T

CL-USER 102 > (handler-case (and (evenp 2)
                                 (/ 3 0)
                                 (oddp 1))
               (error (c)
                 (princ c)
                 (values)))
Division-by-zero caused by / of (3 0).
```